# Strange error with json in node js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I checked all the solutions in stackoverflow but they didn't work with me I can't understand what is happening.

Here's my code:

```
var data = "";
req.on('data', function (chunk) {
    data += chunk;
});
req.on('end', function () {
    // Removed console.log() and after removing it didn't work so Please only answer my question and don't talk about silly things like a missing bracket -_!
    //The error is here
    var json = JSON.parse(data.toString());
    switch (json.method) {
        ...
    }
});
```

And here's console output:

[image: Ubuntu terminal output]

Comment: Is the value from data.toString() actually valid JSON?

Answer (score 0):

its look like your encoding is not set... try to use `res.setEncoding('utf8');`

Answer (score 0):

What does `typeof(data)` returns?

If its a string do not use `toString()`

If its already an object, the `toString()` makes it fail. Also, you do not need to use `JSON.parse()`

Comment: it's a chunk + the output is a split for toString()